# Determining if subset S = [a b c] where a, b, c are rational is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from [Linear algebra](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Algebra.html?id=mYVeAQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y).

The author has proposed the following solution to the problem.

[image]

I think it is wrong.

The result is true but the process is wrong.

The scalar multiplication by an irrational number doesn't belong to `S`, So, `S` is clearly not the subspace.

Am I missing something? or the author is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thought behind their argument is right, but they ought to be more careful in their wording. Just as you say. For instance, they could specify that $f$ is irrational. Or just use some particular well-known irrational number, like $\sqrt2$ or $\pi$ instead of the generic $f$. Or they could have said

> Since $f, 2f$ and $3f$ are not **always** rational numbers, $k\mathbf u$ is not always in the set $S$. Therefore $S$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: thanks for the quick confirmation.